# DJANGO HTML TEMPLATES : How to know Selected item in drop Down and display In the html page without any action

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I want to display the selected item info which is selected  From the drop down in, the same html page without dong any action.How to know which item is selected and how to assign that selected value in a variable in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's onchange event handler to detect when choice is changed and also get the value. There is good example on the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) api page.